# Xamarin.Android: how to switch on Accessibility Service permanently

Tags: android, xamarin

I wrote Accessibility Service to prevent opening of the AlertWindow during USSD request:

```
    [Service(Label = "BalanceAccessibilityService", Permission = "android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE")]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" })]
public class BalanceAccessibilityService : AccessibilityService
{
    static readonly string Tag = "SmsService:" + typeof(BalanceAccessibilityService).Name;
    protected override void OnServiceConnected()
    {
        base.OnServiceConnected();
        AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
        info.Flags = AccessibilityServiceFlags.Default;
        info.PackageNames = new string[] { "com.android.phone" };
        info.EventTypes = EventTypes.WindowStateChanged;
        info.FeedbackType = FeedbackFlags.Generic;
        SetServiceInfo(info);
    }

    public override void OnAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent e)
    {
        Log.Info(Tag, $"onAccessibilityEvent: type = {e.EventType.ToString()} package = {e.PackageName}");

        AccessibilityNodeInfo info = e.Source;

        if (e.EventType == EventTypes.WindowStateChanged && !e.PackageName.Equals("com.android.phone"))
            return;
        if (e.EventType == EventTypes.WindowContentChanged && (info == null || !info.ClassName.Equals("android.widget.TextView")))
            return;
        if (e.EventType == EventTypes.WindowContentChanged && TextUtils.IsEmpty(info.Text))
            return;
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.M)
            PerformGlobalAction(GlobalAction.Back);
        else
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCloseSystemDialogs);
            SendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }

    public override void OnInterrupt()
    {
        Log.Info(Tag, "OnInterrupt");
    }
}
```

All is working but problem is that when my application stopped the switch in Settings->Accessibility->Services->BalanceAccessibilityService switched off. So if I start again my application without switch this switcher on again by hands my service doesn't start. Right now I use such a code for swith it on in onCreate method of the MainActivity:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ActionAccessibilitySettings);
        StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

but I think that it is not normal because for other services such as Power Clean or Android Assistance it is enought to switch it on one time and they never switch off by temselves.
Can anybody tell me where I made an error?

Comment: Did you use VS to  start your app every time?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT, I'm not sure whether I tried to start it by hands... I'll try right now

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT, Yes, thank you very much! The problem was that I launch my application using Xamarin Studio.

Comment: there is an option in the IDE that overwrites all your apps settings and files when you deploy.  If you disable this you won't have the problem.  It only applies to Android, not iOS

Answer (score 1):

I launch my application using Xamarin Studio. In that case after stopping application service switched off. If I launch application by hands service doesn't switch off